# What browsers support the favicon link tag?

Tags: html, favicon

Does anyone what browsers support using the link tag for the favicon, as **opposed to** at the root of the site? I am considering doing that as an alternative to hosting the files at the root of each site because of an issue I'm having an issue in doing so.

The doctype on my two sites are:

First site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

Second site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Browser_implementation

Comment: Doing a little research before asking will prevent down-votes.

Comment: I did spend some time researching this, and did overlook the talbe in this article. Even so, this article doesn't clearly state IE browser versions for the link tag, which was critical to my search @mawcsco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to link to a favicon, which should be supported by all major browsers is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), this way of referencing the icon is supported by Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656%28VS.85%29.aspx), favicons has been supported since IE7.

**Side-note**

I believe using `<link>` instead of just placing it in the root is generally the best strategy anyway. That way you are in control of what icon is displayed. Let's say you want to change the icon sometime in the future. When using a link you can just rename the icon, forcing the browser to download the new icon. Otherwise there is a risk that the user will keep seeing your old icon, as it is loaded from the browser cache.

Comment: The wikipedia article doesn't clearly state IE7 support, so thank you for finding out @Christopher Eliasson